# Neo4J Don't know how to compare that

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm trying to implement simple Spring Neo4j repository function with a List parameter:

```
@Query("MATCH (c:Criterion) WHERE c IN {0} return c")
List<Criterion> getAllCriteria(List<Criterion> criteria);
```

After execution I'm getting following error:

> org.neo4j.cypher.IncomparableValuesException: Don't know how to
>   compare that. Left: Node[513]{name:"Test",description:"Test
>   description"} (NodeProxy); Right:
>   Criterion[id=513,name=Test,description=Test description] (Criterion)

Where I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that lists of parameters are converted.
**Single entities** are converted into their id's.

So if you convert the Criterions into their graph-id's you can do:

```
@Query("MATCH (c:Criterion) WHERE ID(c) IN {0} return c")
List<Criterion> getAllCriteria(List<Long> criteria);
```

Comment: Thanks, works ! One more question, is it possible to automatically convert List<Criteria> to List<Long> without changing the Java code ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Query("MATCH (c:Criterion) WHERE ID(c) IN {0} return c")
List<Criterion> getAllCriteria(List<Criterion> criteria);
```

Even though this might work, your query does seems a bit odd, since the returned list would be equal to what you passed in.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work with the error: scala.MatchError: Criterion[id=641,name=Test,description=Test criterion description] (of class com.example.domain.model.decision.Criterion)